# read memory of another process using address of variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++builder, access-violation, ram

I want to read memory of process A but when the process A is disposed. I have run A, it displays address of some variable, I closed it.

I have run B where I input address of A's variable. It causes error "Access violation...".

I use Borland C++ builder and Windows 7.

Is there any way to watch ram when process is closed? Maybe some tools will help me. Could you give me names of tools to read memory by absolute address after memory deallocation?
Maybe it should be some sort of leak detectors?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know after it is closed, but while running, you can use `ReadProcessMemory()` with `CreateRemoteThread`

Comment: I know about ReadProccesMemory but it use pointer(or handle) of proccess

Comment: Yes, you also have to spawn the process manually to get a handle, or use external mechanisms such as `HPROCESS` from window name.

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory()` is the only safe option. Once you have found and opened the process's handle, the process will not disapear from memory completely until you close your handle to it. You can use any of the `WaitFor...()` family of functions, or the `GetExitCodeProcess()` function, to detect when the process has exited, then read from it and close your handle to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau true true and true.

Answer (score 2):

On most systems, separate processes exist in completely separate *virtual address spaces*.  The pointers you see in one process are completely meaningless in another.

Consequently, you have to explicitly share memory if you want to do this; I'm no Windows expert, but I believe that [`CreateSharedMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa374778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be what you need.

Comment: I want to read memory of some existing application (i.e. Notepad),so i can't to modify it.

Comment: There has to be some solution similar to attaching a debugger to a process (an equivalent to linux `ptrace`), right? It's likely to be fairly complicated, though... [edit: wait, nvm, just saw that OP wants to read the other process' memory AFTER it has finished running...]